# unbound form - update/ append record Validation Rule Violation

Tags: sql, ms-access

I set up an update query to update a record in my main table from a user form. Im sure when I made it it worked fine, now nearing my projects completion Ive gone over everything and its no longer working with "record Validation Rule Violation"  Ive been searching high and low but cannot seem to stop this error, does anyone have any ideas?

The update query is as follows :

```
    Update Inspections SET 
Inspections.Status = [Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![Ins_close], 
Inspections.Assigned_Officer = [Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![Assigned_Officer], 
Inspections.Raised_For = [Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![Raised_For], 
Inspections.INS_Date = [Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![Ins_Date], 
Inspections.INS_Comments = Inspections.INS_Comments & ", " & [Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![Ins_Note] & " " & [Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![User_Initials] & " /  / "
WHERE (((Inspections.INS_ID)=[Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![INS_ID]));
```

I have also tried insert into .... and inserting into a temp table but im always hitting the same issue and cannot work it out

The insert code (which works for creating a new record initially froma  different form.)

```
    INSERT INTO Temp ( Status, Assigned_Officer, Raised_For, INS_Date,  INS_Comments )
Values ([Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![Ins_close],
[Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![Assigned_Officer], 
[Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![Raised_For], 
[Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![Ins_Date], 
[Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![Ins_Note] & " " & [Forms]![Open_All_Edit]![User_Initials] & " \ \ ")
;
```

Comment: I'd check field sizes, `Allow Zero Length`, and `Required` on all fields. that's the likely culprit.  Have you tried running the SQL manually (with the values populated by hand?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(the posted are only about 1/3 of the actual fields i shortened for post)    Simplest thing - After posting this I isolated the field causing the problem and discovered the status field in the table had a validation of open / closed I left in place but I had an option on the form to Close ? yes or no.   ( when I first made it the field was yes/no an changed later )

Its solved now - If its telling you theres a validation error - Check your field validations !